# SVG - Duplicate image along path

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg

I am currently trying to create a bicycle chain via SVG and javascript.

The result I am trying to create will look something like this:
[image: bicycle chain]

The problem I am having is how to repeat a single chainlink image along the path of the chain. I want to be able to use a chainlink image (For example: [image: chainlink]
and then repeat this along the path that I define.

I know that it is trivial to repeat text along a path via SVG but is it possible to do the same with an image? The complexity comes from the fact that the chainlink will have to appear as one continuous line.

Here is what I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <svg width="700" height="500">
   <path id="ChainPath" fill="none" stroke="red" d="M150 100 L400 100 C650 100 650 400 400 400 L150 400" />

   <text>
    <textPath href="#ChainPath" alignment-baseline="middle">
     0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    </textPath>
   </text>
  </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried to practically implement Robert Monfera's answer and found a few extra hitches. I started out computing the points of a polygon sitting, as he described, at the axes/connecting pins of the individual chain links, and all with exactly identical distance between them.

One thing that immediately strikes if you look at it is that a chain is not a smooth line. For the human eye, it might look like one, but describing the chain running around the gear as a circular arc is a bad approximation.

Look at the picture in the question. The right gear has 15 teeth. That means the angle between neighbouring chain links is 24°, and the length difference between an arc and the cord from point to point (which is the constructive length of the link) is approx. 0.8%. That doesn't sound like much, but for a link that you draw with a screen size of 50px, it's almost half a pixel. That is a difference that can be seen.

The next propostion was to use `<marker>` elements for the individual chain links with the origin in the center between the two pins. Since the polygon defined above has its points at the position of the pins, for this a second one is needed that connects the mids of all polygon segments.

When implementing that, the resulting chain looked like this (I've drawn the polygon on top to illustrate):

[image]

Where the "straight" part of the chain morphs to the "curved" one, the chain links are seriously misaligned. The reason is that the marker orientation bisects the incoming and outgoing tangent at a vertex. Both for the straight section and while following the arc of the gear, that works out correctly, but where both meet, it obviously doesn't.

To get the orientation of the markers correct, the tangents at the points must match the direction of the original polygon. Robert proposed to draw an arc between the points. That probaböy would work, but it is complicated to compute the correct arc radii and positions.

I've come up with a method that produces a smooth path that looks a bit crooked, but the line will never show in the end, and its computation is really straightforward - I actually did that with an Excel sheet.

Lets say we have a list of points marking the pin positions:

```
a    b    c    d    e    f    g ...
```

There are two kinds of links (front and back), so mark every other middle of two points:

```
a    b    c    d    e    f    g ...
  ab        cd        ef
```

`a, ab, c` are in a straight line, same as `c, cd, d` and so on. Now if you draw a path with the following command

```
<path d="M a L ab C b c cd d e ef f g ..." marker-mid="url(#link1)" />
```

point `a` will hold no marker, as its not in the middle. The next vertices, which position the markers, are `ab, cd, ef, ...`, while `b, c, d, e, ...` are control points of a cubic Bezier curve. What that means is: the path tangent in vertex `ab` is the straight line from `a` to `b`, in `cd` from `c` to `d`, and so on.

Here is a screenshot from Inkscape to illustrate:

[image]

The other links can be describes accordingly as

```
<path d="M b L bc C c d de e f fg g ..." marker-mid="url(#link2)" />
```

If one wants to get fancy, it is even possible to shorten that a bit with the `S` command that takes the control point before a vertex and implicitely adds its reflection as the next control point after (points `e, g, ...` are computed):

```
<path d="M b L bc C c d de S f fg h hj ..." marker-mid="url(#link2)" />
```

For the grande finale, here is the finished drawing. Just for the heck of it, I've drawn the gear teeths with the same marker technique.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 800 600" width="600" height="450">
  <defs>
    <marker id="blade1" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" overflow="visible">
      <path style="fill:#ececf4" d="M 16.5,-1.556 13.947,-1.78 A 14,14 0 0 1 -13.947,-1.78 L -16.5,-1.556 0,200 Z" />
      <path style="fill:none;stroke:#000" d="M 16.5,-1.556 13.947,-1.78 A 14,14 0 0 1 -13.947,-1.78 L -16.5,-1.556" />
    </marker>
    <marker id="blade2" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" overflow="visible">
      <path style="fill:#ececf4" d="M 16.5,0.507 13.694,-0.089 A 14,14 0 0 1 -13.694,-0.089 L -16.5,0.507 0,90 Z" />
      <path style="fill:none;stroke:#000" d="M 16.5,0.507 13.694,-0.089 A 14,14 0 0 1 -13.694,-0.089 L -16.5,0.507" />
    </marker>
    <path id="plate" d="M -9.689,-10.392 C -4.782 -7.56 4.782 -7.56 9.689,-10.392 A 12,12 0 1 1 9.689,10.392 C 4.782 7.56 -4.782 7.56 -9.689,10.392 A 12,12 0 1 1 -9.689,-10.392 Z" />
    <marker id="link1" style="stroke:#000" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" overflow="visible">
      <use xlink:href="#plate" style="fill:#ddd" />
      <circle id="pin" style="fill:#888;stroke:#000" cx="15.689" cy="0" r="4" />
      <use xlink:href="#pin" x="-31.378" />
    </marker>
    <marker id="link2" style="stroke:#000" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" overflow="visible">
      <use xlink:href="#plate" style="fill:#bbb" />
    </marker>
    <g id="center1">
      <circle r="80" cx="250" cy="300" />
      <g id="cq">
        <circle r="10" cx="345" cy="265.42" />
        <path d="M 252.984,200.049 A 100,100 0 0 1 324.557,233.367 25,25 0 0 0 361.957,200.182 150,150 0 0 0 254.883,150.086 25,25 0 0 0 252.984,200.049 Z" />
      </g>
      <use xlink:href="#cq" transform="rotate(90 250,300)" />
      <use xlink:href="#cq" transform="rotate(180 250,300)" />
      <use xlink:href="#cq" transform="rotate(270 250,300)" />
    </g>
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect fill="white" x="50" y="100" width="400" height="400" />
      <use xlink:href="#center1" fill="black" />
    </mask>
    <path id="center2" d="M 647.75 277.2 L 642.04 279.05 L 643.04 282.13 A 20 20 0 0 0 633.31 292.96 L 630.13 292.28 L 628.88 298.15 L 632.06 298.83 A 20 20 0 0 0 636.55 312.68 L 634.38 315.08 L 638.84 319.1 L 641.01 316.69 A 20 20 0 0 0 655.25 319.73 L 656.25 322.8 L 661.96 320.95 L 660.96 317.87 A 20 20 0 0 0 670.7 307.04 L 673.87 307.72 L 675.12 301.85 L 671.94 301.17 A 20 20 0 0 0 667.45 287.32 L 669.62 284.92 L 665.16 280.9 L 662.99 283.31 A 20 20 0 0 0 648.75 280.27 L 647.75 277.2 z" />
    <mask id="m2">
      <rect fill="white" x="572" y="220" width="160" height="160" />
      <use xlink:href="#center2" fill="black" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#m1)">
    <path style="fill:none;marker-mid:url(#blade1)" d="M 430,300 427.27,331.26 419.14,361.56 405.88,390 387.89,415.7 365.7,437.89 340,455.88 311.56,469.14 281.26,477.27 250,480 218.74,477.27 188.44,469.14 160,455.88 134.3,437.89 112.11,415.7 94.12,390 80.86,361.56 72.73,331.26 70,300 72.73,268.74 80.86,238.44 94.12,210 112.11,184.3 134.3,162.11 160,144.12 188.44,130.86 218.74,122.73 250,120 281.26,122.73 311.56,130.86 340,144.12 365.7,162.11 387.89,184.3 405.88,210 419.14,238.44 427.27,268.74 430,300 427.27,331.26" />
  </g>
  <use xlink:href="#center1" style="fill:none;stroke:#000" />
  <g mask="url(#m2)">
    <path style="fill:none;marker-mid:url(#blade2)" d="M 578.19,315.69 V 284.31 L 590.95,255.65 614.27,234.65 644.11,224.95 675.32,228.23 702.49,243.92 720.94,269.31 727.46,300 720.94,330.69 702.49,356.08 675.32,371.77 644.11,375.05 614.27,365.35 590.95,344.35 578.19,315.69 V 284.31"/>
  </g>
  <use xlink:href="#center2" style="fill:none;stroke:#000" />
  <path style="fill:none;marker-mid:url(#link2)" d="M 281.26 477.27 L 265.63 478.63 C 250 480 218.74 477.27 203.59 473.21 S 160 455.88 147.15 446.89 112.11 415.7 103.11 402.85 80.86 361.56 76.79 346.41 70 300 71.37 284.37 80.86 238.44 87.49 224.22 112.11 184.3 123.21 173.21 160 144.12 174.22 137.49 218.74 122.73 234.37 121.37 281.26 122.73 296.41 126.79 341.88 138.97 357.03 143.03 402.5 155.2 417.66 159.26 463.13 171.43 478.28 175.49 523.75 187.66 538.91 191.72 584.38 203.89 599.54 207.95 645.01 220.12 660.16 224.18 702.49 243.92 711.71 256.61 727.46 300 724.2 315.35 702.49 356.08 688.91 363.92 645.01 379.88 629.85 383.94 584.38 396.11 569.22 400.17 523.75 412.34 508.6 416.4 463.13 428.57 447.97 432.63 402.5 444.8 387.35 448.86 341.88 461.03 326.72 465.09 281.26 477.27 265.63 478.63 L 250 480" />
  <path style="fill:none;marker-mid:url(#link1)" d="M 311.56 469.14 L 296.41 473.21 C 281.26 477.27 250 480 234.37 478.63 S 188.44 469.14 174.22 462.51 134.3 437.89 123.21 426.79 94.12 390 87.49 375.78 72.73 331.26 71.37 315.63 72.73 268.74 76.79 253.59 94.12 210 103.11 197.15 134.3 162.11 147.15 153.11 188.44 130.86 203.59 126.79 250 120 265.63 121.37 311.56 130.86 326.72 134.91 372.19 147.08 387.35 151.14 432.82 163.31 447.97 167.37 493.44 179.54 508.6 183.6 554.07 195.77 569.22 199.83 614.69 212 629.85 216.06 675.32 228.23 688.91 236.08 720.94 269.31 724.2 284.65 720.94 330.69 711.71 343.39 675.32 371.77 660.16 375.82 614.69 388 599.54 392.05 554.07 404.23 538.91 408.28 493.44 420.46 478.28 424.51 432.82 436.69 417.66 440.74 372.19 452.92 357.03 456.97 311.56 469.14 296.41 473.21 L 281.26 477.27" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

In SVG, I define one chainlink and create as many copies as necessary (reference point being at the center of the chainlink) :

```
<use class="chain chainlink1" xlink:href="#chainlink" />
<use class="chain chainlink2" xlink:href="#chainlink" />
<use class="chain chainlink3" xlink:href="#chainlink" />
<use class="chain chainlink4" xlink:href="#chainlink" />
....
```

in the css, I define the path to follow

```
.chain {
   offset-path: path("m 50,150 c -2,-19 12,-36 24,-44 13,-8 176,-54 226,-56 
                      60,0 100,49.17776 100,100 0,51 -42,99 -100,99 C 262,250 
                      95,206 72,191 58,182 50,166 50,150 Z");
   animation: cycle 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes cycle {
  0% { 
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  100% { 
     offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

And the delay of each chainlink

```
.chainlink2 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.chainlink3 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
...
```

Durations and delays depends on length of the chainlink, path... and desired speed

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution: you can make a `<polyline>` or `<polygon>` with `<marker>` elements as long as you're willing to do the math to ensure that the distance between the polygon points exactly match the axis-to-axis distance of your chain element (ie. it's not the total length of the element, but the repeated placement distance that counts). It requires the use of `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` where `c` is this pitch distance (a constant), and `a` and `b` are the horizontal and vertical distances from the preceding point, respectively. In other words, you need to calculate the x, y coordinates of the chain axis centers (*) (if you do that, then you might as well place them one by one, but then you'll have a lot of DOM elements).

You'll need `orient="auto"` to align the chain elements with the polygon, and also use the properties `viewBox`,`refX`, `refY`, `markerWidth`, `markerHeight` so that one of the axes of the chain element aligns perfectly with the polygon point (and then, via using the above Pythagoras theorem, the other chain element center will correspond to the next polygon point).

Here are a few examples for the `<marker>`:

- https://codepen.io/monfera/pen/ppaRNK
- https://codepen.io/monfera/pen/xXmpbY
- https://codepen.io/monfera/pen/oLoRgX

As I look at your chain (normal bicycle chain), it's best to make two almost identical polygons atop of one another, with a half-pitch offset between the two:

- in the background, the partially occluded chain elements
- in the foreground, the 8-shaped, fully visible link plates

As a result, your chain will be seamless, as long as your points are at the right place. You can even set up a loop of transitioning between adjacent elements for an animated chain :-) (it's enough to transition with the chain pitch only, because a chain pitch translation will get you back to an indistinguishable view)

(*) As ccprog points out [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555417/svg-duplicate-image-along-path/50555701?noredirect=1#comment88154042_50555701), to make the individual chain elements better aligned, it's not an axis center but the chain center that must sit on the polygon. This might make the math a bit more tedious if there are sharp turns, but in this specific case (bicycle chain) the circle radii seem sufficiently large to not lead to a noticeable separation of the chain elements.

Comment: Ah, one more thing: you can use `getPointAtLength` to help with the point positions this way: 1. render the shape, using lines, arcs ie. via the `<path>` element; then get x, y coordinates at a regular cadence by invoking `getPointAtLength`. The `<path>` doesn't need to show up but it'll be occluded anyway. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868

Comment: While this is a good start, you are wrong in one assumption: the marker orientation [bisects the incoming and outgoing tangent at a vertex](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#OrientAttribute). That means if you set the marker origin at one axis, the other will end outside the curve, for a variable amount depending on the angle between the chain elements. Instead, set the marker origin to the middle of the chain link, and redraw the polygon as a path with its vertices in the middle between the polygon points, and smooth curves so that the tangent is parallel to the polygon segment.

Comment: "the circle radii seem sufficiently large to not lead to a noticeable separation of the chain elements" - unfortunately not true. I've dabbled around and using a polygon leads to very visible hitches where straight and curved segments meet. You really need those correct tangents.

Comment: The arcs `a`/`A` in the SVG `path` minilanguage seem to enable the direct use of circular arcs, probably with a correction as the chord is slightly shorter than the arc for a given circle angle and radius, depending on the parameters. I.e. the arcs should form a circle that fit inside the polygon formed by the chain link axes.

Comment: True, but relatively complicated to compute. Since you seem to be interested, I'll post my practical experiment as a second answer.